# JObject Pattern Matching: Merging partial WEB API JSON payload

Tags: c#, json, fluent-interface, json.net, fluent-assertions

This library [[GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/JMap)] helps merging partial WEB API JSON payload with existing prepopulated DTO objects.

Let's say that JSON is represented by JObject from JSON.NET package. Naïve implementation will probably get us to the following code for the optional string property mapping:

```
var jToken = jObject["optionalScalar"];
if(jToken!= null)
     dto.OptionalScalar = jToken.Value<string>();
```

where required mapping would need throwing an exception:

```
var jToken = jObject["requiredScalar "];
if(jToken!= null)
     dto.RequiredScalar = jToken.Value<string>();
else
     throw new MissingFieldException("requiredScalar");
```

Collection mapping is even more verbose, as we need to instantiate/find necessary DTO for collection items and perform the same logic as above on their individual properties.

`JMap` library allows to define this mapping declaratively and execute necessary requests to external data sources concurrently.

Given the following example JSON loaded into the JObject `job`:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "tester",
  "company": {
      "name": "Microsoft",
      "size": 50000,
      "industries": [
         { "id": 1 },
         { "id": 2 }
      ]
   },
   "types": [ "Full-Time", "Part-Time" ],
   "locations": [
      {
         "city": "Vancouver",
         "country": "Canada"
      }
   ]
}
```

We could map it to the following DTO structure:

```
public class DtoJob
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DtoCompany Company { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Types { get; set; }
    public IList<DtoLocation> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class DtoCompany
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public IList<DtoIndustry> Industries { get; set; }
}

public class DtoLocation
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public interface IIndustryReader
{
    DtoIndustry ReadIndustry(int id);
    Task<DtoIndustry> ReadIndustryAsync(int id);
}

public class DtoIndustry
{
     ...
}
```

Using the following declaration:

```
await job.MapAsync()
  .RequiredAssert((int id) => id == dtoJob.Id)
  .Optional((string title) => dtoJob.Title)
  .Optional((JObject company) => dtoJob.Company, (company, dtoCompany) => company
      .Optional((string name) => dtoCompany.Name)
      .Optional((int size) => dtoCompany.Size)
      .Optional((JObject[] industries) => dtoCompany.Industries, industry => 
          IndustryReader.ReadIndustryAsync(industry.Id())))
      .Optional((string[] types) => dtoJob.Types)
      .Optional((JObject[] locations) => dtoJob.Locations, (location, dtoLocation) => location
          .Required((string city) => dtoLocation.City)
          .Required((string country) => dtoLocation.Country));
```

Where lines like this:

```
.RequiredAssert((int id) => id == dtoJob.Id)
```

Represent a necessary condition to check, while

```
.Optional((string title) => dtoJob.Title)
```

Defines an automatic coercion between string in JSON to the data type of the `dtoJob.Title` property, while

```
.Optional((JObject[] industries) => dtoCompany.Industries, industry => 
    IndustryReader.ReadIndustryAsync(industry.Id())))
```

Defines a conversion from `JObject` array to collection of some DTO objects loaded concurrently from the database and assigned to the `dtoCompany.Industries` property, while

```
 .Optional((JObject company) => dtoJob.Company, (company, dtoCompany) => company
     .Optional((string name) => dtoCompany.Name)
     .Optional((int size) => dtoCompany.Size)
     .Optional((JObject[] industries) => dtoCompany.Industries, industry => 
         IndustryReader.ReadIndustryAsync(industry.Id())))
```

Defines a merge of JObject `company` field content to `dtoJob.Company` object, creating one if missing.

As shown, there are the following permutations of mapping declarations:

- Optional/Required
- Coercion/Conversion/Merge
- JSON type for pattern matching could be:

  - a string, int, long, float, doable, bool, DateTime;
  - their nullable counterparts;
  - JObject;
  - An array of above.

What would you say about this way to declare mapping?

Comment: I'm afraid this time it might be off-topic because there is no actuall code but just a few theoretical examples nevertheless I find the `Optional` tree really ugly :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t Examples are quotes from the real project, I'm trying to bring the mapping code for the review - expressiveness of it is under the question. I would prefer to keep the library implementation details out of scope - it is just a stupid 32 files with all the permutations... Ready to remove it though, if you think so.

Comment: @t3chb0t How would you otherwise express Optional/Required mappings between two object trees in code?

Comment: I wouldn't and I would do everthing to not have this mess. I find such mappings is really the last resort solution. It's super fragile and super complex to configure. I always wonder why people do that?

Comment: If I got your use case correctly then you are mapping 1:1 from some entity to a dto... this is even more unnecessary. Why not use the actuall type from the beginning? Why the dto layer? This is the most useless thing, sorry ;-)

Comment: I understand separation but mappings from entities to dto is an total overkill and even more types but this time with the weird dto prefix. I can understand using something like Automapper for some ancient legacy code but using it in a new solution is a sign of overengineering and of a bad design.

Comment: Because I can not allow JSON deserializer to create the whole object graph for me. I do need to merge partial JSON content (some config file or JSON payload) with existing object graph. I also need to perform some sync/async storage requests to read some sub-objects  by, let's say, their IDs and put then in the target graph. I would like this operations to run concurrently. This snippet does all that stuff.

Comment: The question is - if you could see it all in the code? :) Is it readable enough? This snippet replaces approx 300 lines one need to write otherwise to have all this logic.

Comment: Well, all one can say from this small snippet is that the entire mapping seems to be unnecessary especially that almost everything is optional. Wouldn't it be easier to decorate the dto-properties with some attributes and let the merge utility figure out the rest?

Comment: I find it's too much and you should only need to define mappings that cannot be figured out automatically because they map _FirstName_ to _FullName_ etc. But 1:1 mappings should not have to be described. Only the _exceptions_ and customizations.

Comment: @t3chb0t I would have a hard time injecting dependencies into the merge utilities. Can you see how conversion lambdas use readers (e.g. IndustryReader)? It is a way simpler to capture them in closures.

Comment: @t3chb0t It looks like a fight between attributes versus fluid configuration API in EF. I would always vote for the fluid one. In my case here I can also support multiple API versions these way. It's not exactly one to one - the only matching thing is cardinality - graph shapes could and should be (with time) different.

Comment: _graph shapes [..] should be [..] different_ this is a horrible scenario. Why would you want to do this? I wouldn't like to have to maintain this ;-( well, there don't have to be any attributes at all. If most of the properties are mapped and only some should be excluded then you just say which ones to exclude/ignore from mapping. Configuring everything even things that can be determined automatically is IMO unnecessasry that's why I find the _Optional_ tree hard to read and to maintain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58011/discussion-between-dmitry-nogin-and-t3chb0t).